# Python. Как сделать интерфейс для программы без сторонних модулей и библиотек?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, python-3.6

Хочу сделать интерфейс программы, но не хочу использовать tkinter, qiwi, qt и т.д. Помогите пожалуйста. Может есть какая то литература?

Comment: Но зачем? Вы в одиночку сможете сделать только интерфейс, привязанный к конкретной ОС. Вам придётся изучать низкоуровневую работу с экраном в этой ОС и т.д. Сделать можно, но придётся изучать много информации, которая скорее всего вам потом никак не пригодится. И которая не имеет почти никакого отношения собственно к питону.

Comment: а как тогда работают другие фреймворки модули? они же тоже на питоне написаны?

Comment: Ну, самая верхняя логика - да, на питоне, а низкоуровневая часть обычно на С++ с вызовом всяких библиотек операционки.

Comment: так с++ это же высокоуровневый язык

Comment: Он на любой уровень. Но он мягко говоря своеобразный и больше подходит всё же для низкоуровневых вещей

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Базовыми средствами Python это невозможно.

Comment: Да, тоже хотел написать: python - это не про GUI - интерфейс. Во всяком случае, без тех штук, котрые автор вопроса перечислил

Comment: а как тогда они реализовали это в питоне? :/ qt, qiwi. Это же все тоже на питоне

Comment: @Dariuz Там идет привязка к С++ библиотеке. Почитайте про SIP.
P.S. Да и вообще вопрос странный я не могу придумать в какой ситуации нельзя пользоваться сторонними графическими интерфейсами.

Comment: В ситуации, когда хочешь оптимизировать свою программу до максимума, либо создать свой фреймворк

Comment: @Dariuz Оптимизируют не так. А фреймворк вы будете несколько лет писать

Answer (score 0):

Написать свою библиотеку-интерфейс на питоне, скорее всего, возможно(хотя не представляю как). Вопрос состоит в том, сколько времени ты на это потратишь, тк python довольно высокоуровневый для написания таких библиотек. Ближайшая интерфейс-библиотека - Pyqt, написана на "C++". thinker написан на "Tcl". Какой вывод: либо писать на более низкоуровневом языке, либо использовать то что уже есть.